# How can i make a custom file explorer with an HTA application?

Tags: hta

I want to make a custom file explorer to go through the files and folders like you would with the normal window explorer. I want it to have the same basic function like being able to go folder to folder and back up to the previous folders and be able to open and execute files and such. How can i do this? Can anyone help get me started?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure HTA still runs? I thought it was killed of by various security enhancements? Assuming a HTA runs Javascript OK, here are some javascript libraries that have interactive file tree functionality:

http://john-smith-js.com/filetree.html

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/

Post back if you would like to continue down this path.